# Save a figure without white space pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I have the following code that creates a spectrogram. The problem I have is when I save the figure, there is white space where the axis used to be, I am wondering if it is possible to remove it?

```
x, y = np.mgrid[:len(times), :len(hist_bins_khz)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, np.swapaxes(amplitudes_logged, 0, 1))
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("testfile.png"),bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: Does if work if you add `ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])`, and remove `bbox_inches='tight'`?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you!

Comment: @onewhaleid you should put your answer as an answer. It will make it easier for future people with the same problem to see the answer, as well as giving you more reputation if it is upvoted/accepted

Comment: I would if I could, but for some reason I am not able to mark it as the answer.